# Master slave widget for PloneFormGen

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

Does there exist anything akin "Master Slave Widget" for PloneFormGen? Where the user choices first choice A which would generate the list of choices for choice B (below) to select?

Answer (score 3):

This is a far less than ideal answer, but I've done this several times with JavaScript injected into the header with a PFG override. It's only practical for relatively simple decision trees.

The basic procedure is to on-load hide all the subsidiary controls, then reveal them as click events indicate a controlling choice. Grouping subsidiary controls into fieldsets is also handy: then you may show and hide controls as a group.