# Ploneformgen form validate value of 1 field against input of another

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

I have a form select field. Based on the option selected, I would like to input the value of another text field. If an option is selected, the text field should be blurred i.e return false, else it should allow text to be entered mandatorilyI need sample code desperately. Using plone 4.1.4, Ploneformgen 1.7.9

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729963/master-slave-widget-for-ploneformgen

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this by using a custom validation override, and looking at the data you get in the request (probably a have `request` object, or fallback to `context.REQUEST`).